# É possível em um componente existir um map que muda o retorno de acordo com a prop que foi passada?

Tags: react

```
<tbody>
   {props.item.map((film) => (
     <tr>
       <td>{film.name}</td>
       <td>{film.mass}</td>
       <td>{film.height}</td>
       <td>{film.birth_year}</td>
      </tr>
     ))}
</tbody>
```

Gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma dessa parte da td ser composta por outras informações. Tipo, se eu fizer uma requisição em outra URL e me retornar objetos com outras propriedades, se teria como essa td ficar de forma dinâmica sem criar outro componente para receber essas informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se estou entendendo muito bem sua pergunta. Mais seria assim?

```
<tbody>
   {props.item.map((film) => (
     <tr>
       { Object.keys(film).map((chaveDeObj) => 
          (<td>{film[chaveDeObj]}</td>) }
      </tr>
     ))}
</tbody>
```

também daria para criar um objeto `<thead>` usando a `chaveDeObj` como valor. Isso libera voce trocar o objeto `film` para qualquer outro sem saber o seu conteúdo.  Claro que isso so funciona com objetos simples, mais da para modificar para lidar com objetos mais complexos.

O certo e ter algum tipo de filtro para não demostrar valores que não são necessários.

Da para fazer algo assim:

```
import React from 'react';

// props: { filtro: string[]; itens: any[] }
const genericTable = (props) => {
  const filtrosDeChaves = props.filtro; // ex.: ['nome', 'data']
  return (
    <>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {filtrosDeChaves.map((chave) => (
            <td key={chave}>{chave}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.itens.map((
          item, // mudei o nome do obj para itens
          index // estou usando index para key mais o certo seria outro valor
        ) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            {Object.keys(item)
              .filter(
                // filtrar para valores desejados
                (chaveDoItem) => filtrosDeChaves.includes(chaveDoItem)
              )
              .map((chaveDoItem) => (
                <td key={chaveDoItem}>{item[chaveDoItem]}</td>
              ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Entendi, me ajudou bastante. Muito obrigado!